# How to sort albums in years and artists

Tags: itunes

I am a iTunes novice :(
I have various songs and albums on my itunes and would like to get into some kind of order.
My question is:
Can I sort out all the albums from one artist into ascending years and still keep other albums in order?
For example, I have albums by Coldplay and other albums by various artists. If I click on the year column, all the library is mixed. Can I arrange it so only the Coldplay albums are sorted into years and not the whole library is sorted?
Thank you

Comment: Are you on iTunes 11?

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is ITunes 11 (Earlier iTunes gave better options)

In album view: From the menus choose View->View Options and then choose the sort by as Artist and then as Year. You get all albums. I suspect this is nearest to what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how: create a new Smart Playlist -- the command is under the File => New menu -- in the the left side panel of iTunes.

In the resulting dialog box, set the playlist to Artist is ColdPlay. The resulting display will show only ColdPlay songs.

You can now sort the display as you wish.